# How to pivot some of data fields in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I tried using max(case) but it didn't work to convert the unpivot data to pivot format.

Can we pivot this data in the following format?

My table:

```
Create table mytable (id integer,indicator text,value text);

Insert into mytable (id, indicator, value) values (1,'indicator 1', '10');
Insert into mytable (id, indicator, value) values (1,'indicator 2', 'yes');
Insert into mytable (id, indicator, value) values (1,'indicator 3', '123');
Insert into mytable (id, indicator, value) values (1,'state', 'ns');
Insert into mytable (id, indicator, value) values (1,'district', 'yr');
Insert into mytable (id, indicator, value) values (1,'block', 'ty');
```

| id | indicator | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | indicator 1 | 10 |
| 1 | indicator 2 | yes |
| 1 | indicator 3 | 123 |
| 1 | state | ns |
| 1 | district | yr |
| 1 | block | ty |

Output should be like below:

| id | state | district | block | indicator | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ns | yr | ty | indicator 1 | 10 |
| 1 | ns | yr | ty | indicator 2 | yes |
| 1 | ns | yr | ty | indicator 3 | 123 |

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement a key-value store in a relational database? You're now already encountering the first problems

Comment: you can use `crosstab()` function, but you'd first have to enable `tablefunc` in your DB. You can enable it by executing `create extension tablefunc;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to pivot the state/district/block rows to columns, while retaining "indicator" rows.

One option uses window function to pivot, then filters:

```
select id, state, district, block, indicator, value
from (
    select t.*,
        max(value) filter(where indicator = 'state')    over(partition by id) as state,
        max(value) filter(where indicator = 'district') over(partition by id) as district,
        max(value) filter(where indicator = 'block')    over(partition by id) as block
    from mytable t
) t
where indicator like 'indicator%'
```

| id | state | district | block | indicator | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ns | yr | ty | indicator 1 | 10 |
| 1 | ns | yr | ty | indicator 2 | yes |
| 1 | ns | yr | ty | indicator 3 | 123 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RO97Vmva)